# should i increase threadpool?

Tags: threadpool, jvisualvm, resource-management

I am seeing almost 99% of thread in park/wait condition and 1% in running out of threadpool of size 100. CPU usage  is 25% and memory just 2GB out of 6 GB allocated. Should I increase threadpool size? I think so because system has enough resource and more threads will utilize it properly to increase througput.

Comment: If almost all threads are waiting or parked, I would say you have issues with concurrency in the application and adding more threads won't help. Or there are already more threads than needed.

Comment: I guess there are already more than required thread. Its just that load on my application vary too much .Its 4x vs x in peak vs low time and I need to have more threads for peak time.